# Write a short proof for the following statement: Let n be a positive integer. Statement 1. If$ (\forall x\in \mathbb N, n|x)$, then n=1

Tags: linear-algebra

Write a short proof for the following statement:

Let n be a positive integer.

Statement 1. If $(\forall x\in \mathbb N, n|x)$, then $n=1$.

The proof I tried to explain is that since for every $x\in \mathbb N, n|x n=1$ is set.

Since $n=1$ and $x$ belongs to every natural number $1$ is divisible by every natural number.

Can I just say that?

Answer (score 1):

No. You want to do something like this : If $n\mid x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$, then in particular,
$$
n\mid 2 \text{ and } n\mid 3
$$
Since the gcd of 2 and 3 is 1, it follows that $n\mid 1 \Rightarrow n=1$

Comment: Why work so hard? If $n\mid x$ for each $x\in\Bbb N$, then $n\mid 1$. The only divisors of $1$ are $\pm1$, and we’re told that $n$ is a positive integer, so $n=1$.

Comment: So for the statement,

Let a and b be integers such that b ≠ 0.

Statement 1. If b = 3a, then a^2|b^2.

Would my proof in going about this be correct?

b^2 = k*a^2

b^2 = 9a^2

k = 9

Therefore since b^2 = 9a^2, then a^2|9a^2, then the statement is true?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] since for every $x \in \def\NN{\mathbb N}\NN$, $n\mid x$ $n=1$ is set.

What does that even mean?!

> Since $n=1$ and $x$ belongs to every natural number $1$ is divisible by every natural number.

I think you meant to write that every natural number is divisible by $1$, but what do you mean with the first part?!

This is bordering on [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) territory.

A proper proof would go by for example proving the contraposed statement, i.e. that if $n \neq 1$ then there is an $x \in \NN$ such that $n \nmid x$ which is obvious: just take $x=n+1$.

Comment: Or it would observe that $n\mid 1$, and the only positive divisor of $1$ is $1$.